# Java - Lemmings - How to detect mouse over lemming

Tags: java, 2d

My first post on gamedev :) And my first go at game dev :D

To ease me in, I'm starting with a lemmings clone.

I have my lemmings moving about and already have a `MouseAdapter` for moving around the map with the mouse.

In order to detect when the mouse is over a lemming I thought the easiest way
would be to override the `mouseMoved` method. This would iterator over the lemmings and check if the mouse coords are in the lemmings rectangle. Is the normal way to do this?

I realised this wouldn't work for a lemming walking under/past the mouse cursor.

Comment: I'd say just check when you need to. Do you need to check for lemmings every time you move your mouse? Probably not. So instead check when you're trying to perform an action that requires the mouse to be above the lemming.

Comment: Maybe you're too young to have played the original Lemmings :) Cursor needs to change when either the mouse is moved over a lemming or when a lemming walks under the mouse cursor.

Comment: Very true haha but that wasn't my point. My point was that those events don't happen when you move your mouse, they happen whenever the game updates (new frame) so your code should check every frame not just when you move your mouse :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by having a second mask just for the "lemmings", then I can check this every time it paints.